# Is this extension cyclic? proof of Dummit and Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am reading this lemma of Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote page 628.
The only line that I couldn't understand this -5 line. Is $F'/F$ cyclic? As far as I understood, $F'$ is an extension over F, adjoining all needed roots of unit. But if $\boldsymbol{\zeta}_{n}$ denote a generator of multiplicative group of nth root of unity, which is cyclic, it is not always true that $Gal(F(\boldsymbol{\zeta}_{n})/F)$ cyclic, isn't it?

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to include only the relevant mathematics (rather than force people to go through a whole-page proof) and to typeset the relevant mathematics (rather than including an image, which throws off site searches).

Comment: @GregMartin Do you mean it's better to type? Isn't it better to put whole proof to understand the overall flows and situation?

Comment: Yes it's better to type, and no it's not better to put a whole proof when your question is about a specific part of it (potential helpers aren't going to be interested in reading an entire proof just to get to the question).